# Outlier in linear algorithm for nth Fibonacci

Tags: performance, fibonacci

So I was taught that using the recurrence relation of Fibonacci numbers, I could get an O(n) algorithm. But, due to the large size of Fibonacci numbers for large n, the addition takes proportionally longer : meaning that, the time complexity is no longer linear.

That's all well and fine but in this graph ([source](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/on-the-linear-time-algorithm-for-finding-fibonacci-numbers/)), why is there a number near 1800000 which takes significantly longer to compute than it's neighbours?

EDIT: As mentioned in the answers, the outlier is around 180000, not 1800000

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> probably the measurement of time was done on a system where other
>   tasks were performed simultaneously, which was causing a single
>   computation to take longer than expected.

Part of the graph that the OP didn't copy says:

> Note: Each data point was averaged over 10 calculcations[sic].

So that seems to negate that explanation unless it was a ***huge*** difference and we're only seeing it averaged with normal times.

(My 2012 vintage Mac mini calculates the 200,000th number in 1/2 a second using the author's code.  The machine that produced this data took over 4 seconds to calculate the 200,000th number. I pulled out a 2009 vintage MacBook to confirm that this is believable.)

I did my own crude graph with a modified version of the code that didn't restart at the beginning each time but kept a running total of the time and came up with the following chart:

[image]

The times are a bit longer than expected as the algorithm I used adds some printing overhead into each calculation.  But no big anomaly between 180,000 and 195,000.

Answer (score 1):

The outlier occurred at 180,000, not 1,800,000. I don't know how big integers are stored in python, but assuming 32 bit words stored as binary, fib(180000) takes close to 100,000 bytes. I suspect an issue with the testing for why 180,000 would take significantly longer than 181,000 or 179,000.

@cdlane mentioned the time it would take for fib(170000) to fib(200000), but the increment is 1000, so that would be 30 test cases, run 10 times each, which would take less than 20 minutes.

The article linked to mentioned a matrix variation for calculating Fibonacci number which is a log2(n) process. This can be further optimized using a Lucas sequence which is similar logic (repeated squaring for raising a matrix to a power). Example C code for 64 bit unsigned integers:

```
uint64_t fibl(uint64_t n) {
    uint64_t a, b, p, q, qq, aq;
    a = q = 1;
    b = p = 0;
    while(1) {
        if(n & 1) {
            aq = a*q;
            a = b*q + aq + a*p;
            b = b*p + aq;
        }
        n >>= 1;
        if(n == 0)
            break;
        qq = q*q;
        q = 2*p*q + qq;
        p = p*p + qq;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I missed the increment of 1000 buried in the comments of the original article.  Python would switch from int representation to bignums around n = 93 which unfortunately can't be seen on the graph at increments of 1000.